# PHP Kirby Use 2 variables in 1 Snippet

Tags: php, variables, code-snippets, kirby

I'm really new to Kirby and PHP and I try to use 2 variables in a Snippet.
This is my Code right now

```
<div class="container">

<h2><?= $variable1 ?></h2>


<?php
foreach (page('blogs')
  ->children()
  ->listed()
  ->filterBy('tags', 'variable2', ',')
  ->flip() as $subpage) :

  snippet('blogkarte', ['subpage' => $subpage]);
?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

I understand how to use the $title method for Variable1, but it don't work with Variable2

`<?php snippet('blogkarten', ['variable1' => 'MYTEXT"', 'variable2' => "MYTEXT"]) ?>`

This is the way I tried, but it didn't worked...

I hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the second parameter of your `filterBy()` method is a hard-coded **string literal**: PHP is not seeing is as a 'variable named $variable2', but rather as the literal string "variable2".

If you're correctly passing a variable named `$variable2` to your snippet, and you want to use it as the second parameter in your `filterBy()` method, you just need to do this:

```php
->filterBy('tags',$variable2,',')
```